# Windows Batch: Comparing time and string literals

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have coded a batch script that **would ran an .exe if the filename from a directory is equivalent to its expected filename, on a given time range**.

For example, the files from the path are "file1" and "file2", while process_one = "file1" and process_two = "file2"

The result is it would always go to the first if statement even if the condition is false.

What is not working here is the if-statement. 
e.g.
file1 = "filenameA.txt"; process_one = "filenmameB.txt"

it would always execute the command in first if-statement even if it is false.

Have I compared the time and string literals correctly? if not, what is the proper comparison for time and string literals?

Here is what I've done so far. I'm quite new here, so thank you for all the insights. :)

```
@echo off

For /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x

SET EnabledDelayedExpansion

SET folderPath=D:\InputFiles

SET month=%MyDate:~4,2%
SET day=%MyDate:~6,2%
SET year=%MyDate:~0,4%
SET dateToday=%year%%month%%day%
SET currentTime=%Time: =0%

SET filename1=filename1_%dateToday%.dat
SET filename2=filename2_%dateToday%.dat
SET filename3=filename3_%dateToday%.dat
SET filename4=filename4_%dateToday%.dat
SET filename5=filename5_%dateToday%.dat
SET filename6=filename6_%dateToday%.dat
::SET count=0

pushd "%folderPath%"
for %%F in (*.*) do (  
    ::set /a count+=1
    ::echo %%~nxF       
IF "%%~nxF"=="%filename1%" (
    IF %currentTime% GEQ 01:30:00.00 IF %currentTime% LEQ 23:00:00.00 ( start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Activity\activities.exe" -process acta )
    )               
IF "%%~nxF"=="%filename2%" (
    IF %currentTime% GEQ 02:00:00.00 IF %currentTime% LEQ 18:05:59.59 ( start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Activity\activities.exe" -process actb )
    )
IF "%%~nxF"=="%filename3%" ( 
    IF %currentTime% GEQ 03:00:00.00 IF %currentTime% LEQ 19:00:00.00 ( start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Activity\activities.exe" -process actc )
    )
IF "%%~nxF"=="%filename4%" ( 
    IF %currentTime% GEQ 04:25:00.00 IF %currentTime% LEQ 19:00:00.00 ( start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Activity\activities.exe" -process actd )
    )
IF "%%~nxF"=="%filename5%" (
    IF %currentTime% GEQ 05:00:00.00 IF %currentTime% LEQ 23:59:59.59 ( start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Activity\activities.exe" -process acte )
    )
IF "%%~nxF"=="%filename6%" ( 
    IF %currentTime% GEQ 06:00:00.00 IF %currentTime% LEQ 23:59:59.59 ( start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Activity\activities.exe" -process actf )
    )
)
popd
```

Comment: and what is not working with your script?

Comment: `) & popd` this means that `popd` will be executed on each iteration. Why is not put on separate line but appended to the for loop?

Comment: Overwriting the PATH variable with your own PATH variable is usually not a good idea.

Comment: Calling to a label is just slowing down your batch file.  You have no need to do it in this instance. In your example you could just do everything inside the FOR block.  You could just do an `IF EXIST` command instead of conditional execution of the FOR command.

Comment: Where have you defined your process variables.  That code is relevant.

Comment: @npocmaka - i edited the post. oooh, i see, i'll try that.

Comment: @Squashman i have defined the variables before the pushd command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix to the code may just be to replace your bottom two lines with:

```bat
If /I "%fileName%"=="%process_one%" Start "" /B "process.exe" -process "%process_one%"
If /I "%fileName%"=="%process_two%" Start "" /B "process.exe" -process "%process_two%"
```

I'd however suggest you should remove `pushd "%path%" &&` and `& popd` or at least change `(%path%\*.*)` to `(*.*)`.
Assuming there are no errors in the section of the script you have decided to omit, here's a best guess rewrite/replacement of the code you've posted:

```bat
If Not Exist "%_path%\" Exit/B 1

For %%F In (%_path%\*.*) Do (Set/A count+=1
    For %%G In ("%process_one%" "%process_two%") Do If /I "%%~nxF"==%%G (
        Start "" /B "process.exe" -process %%G))

Exit/B 0
```

***Important notes***:
You need to make sure you already have an integer variable named `%count%` set, *probably `Set "count=0"`*. If however you're not using `%count%` elsewhere in the script, you can ignore that advice and remove `Set/A count+=1` from the code I've provided above. You need to change variable name in any part of the script you haven't posted from `%path%` to `%_path%`. *You have already stated that you already have string variables named `%process_one%` and `%process_two%` set*.

Comment: i see, i tried to do the suggested solution but the problem is, it always execute the command in the first if statement...it always starts the process in first if statement. i have of than if statement by theway, and each if commands contain the process where it execute a specific .exe file

Comment: You need to post your entire script then so that we can debug the rest of your code.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't tell us what you were really doing, you cannot use the **`GEQ`/`LEQ`** comparisons like that with times, especially those containing characters like **`:`**.

Comment: what I'm doing is, it should run a specific application if the filename is equal to the expected file name, and if the current time is in the time range.

Comment: I'm aware of that, it's just you cannot do it like that. I'd suggest you post a new question asking specifically for help with comparing time strings within ranges, or completely overhaul your opening post accordingly.