# Batch Scripting: Invoking start command inside an if-block statement

Tags: batch-file

This is a continuation from this post:[Comparing string literals and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170004/windows-batch-comparing-time-and-string-literals/42186682?noredirect=1#comment71569744_42186682)

Comparing string literals and time are now correct, thanks to all of you who have contributed to my previous question.

However, the persisting issue lies on invoking "start" command inside the if-block statement.

Let's see this code,

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


For /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x


SET triggerFolderPath=D:\InputFiles

SET month=%MyDate:~4,2%
SET day=%MyDate:~6,2%
SET year=%MyDate:~0,4%
SET dateToday=%year%%month%%day%
SET currentTime=%Time: =0%

.
.
.

for %%F in (%triggerFolderPath%\*.*) do ( 
    echo %%~nxF     

    IF "%%~nxF"=="file_one.txt" (
        IF %currentTime:~0,2% GEQ 18 ( IF %currentTime:~0,2% LEQ 23 ( echo success 
            echo process_one
            start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Process.exe" -process ProcessOne ))
        )               
    IF "%%~nxF"=="file_two.txt" (
        IF %currentTime:~0,2% GEQ 08 ( IF %currentTime:~0,2% LEQ 23 ( echo success
            echo process_two
            start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Process.exe" -process ProcessTwo ))
.
.
.

        )
endlocal

exit /b 0
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Given: %%~nxf = file_two; 
I added echo command to see if the condition was hit.

The program was able to output the echos for this if conditions

```
IF "%%~nxF"=="file_two" (
    IF %currentTime:~0,2% GEQ 08 ( IF %currentTime:~0,2% LEQ 23 ( echo success
        echo process_two
        start /b "" "C:\Program Files\Process.exe" -process ProcessTwo ))
    )
```

**However the error is,it keeps on executing ProcessOne, instead of ProcessTwo.** I tried to put the start command right after opening parenthesis "(" or before the command, but it still processes ProcessOne. Why does it process ProcessOne if it is isn't included in the latter if-block statement that processes ProcessTwo/

Comment: Considering you are using a FOR command variable, this code is inside a code block.  So if the currentTime variable is set within this code block, it then needs to be referenced with Delayed Expansion.  So you are not showing us all the code that is having an affect on your existing problem.

Comment: While I still stand by my previous statement, you are going to run into issues with leading zeros in your numbers.  Take this for example: `IF 1 GTR 08 echo yes`.  This will actually output yes.

Comment: @Squashman, hello, I have edited my post. For your recent comment, i think this `SET currentTime=%Time: =0%` reduces the issue with leading zeros... is it right?

Comment: Numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal numbers, so `08` and `09` are invalid numbers, in which case `if` does string comparison rather than numberic one; you could do `set "currentTime=%Time: =0%"`, then `if 1%currentTime:0,2% GEQ 118` to force numberic comparison...

Answer (score 0):

everyone!
Thanks again for your insights. I have learned a lot in batch scripting.

I have found the root cause of the issue. .dll files for the application that I have to call inside the FOR loop are not updated. So, make sure that when you are running an application, dll files or all the files needed to run that application are up to date.

Also, I used CALL instead of START to call the .exe file. the program runs smoothly as compared when using START

Thanks again!